# How to add product options in category page in opencart 2.0

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to add product options in the category page in opencart 2.0.

I have added this code in  \catalog\model\catalog\product.php

```
public function hasOptionPriceIncrease($product_id) {
   $option_data = $this->getProductOptions($product_id);
if (is_array($product_option_value)) {
  foreach ($product_option_value as $option) {
  if (is_array($option['product_option_value'])) {
    foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $value) {
      if ($value['price'] > 1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
} return false }
```

and then in \controller\product\category.php

```
'has_option_price_increase' =>$this->model_catalog_product->hasOptionPriceIncrease($result['product_id'])
```

so now in category $this->data['products'][] becomes something like this-

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
'thumb'       => $image,
'name'        => $result['name'],
'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
'price'       => $price,
'special'     => $special,
'tax'         => $tax,
'rating'      => $result['rating'],
'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url),
'has_option_price_increase' =>$this->model_catalog_product->hasOptionPriceIncrease($result['product_id'])
);
```

Now i didn't understand how to call this in my view i.e., in collection.tpl

Please help me to display this in my view, to show the product options in category page.

Comment: Hey @jx12345 , i have seen that you also done the same thing, can you please help me with view buddy

Comment: Can you please elaborate it in terms of how it you wants to show that price in front end ?

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours doing this but I got it working. Now, I only needed the SELECT so you go and modified it to your needs in the category.tpl I'm using version 2.1.0.2

1- Go to /catalog/controller/product/category.php 
Then >> Find the product array

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
```

2- Add this code above the array

```
foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($result['product_id']) as $option) {

                                    foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {

                                             $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                        'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                        'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                        'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                        'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                        'price'                   => $price,
                        'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                    );
                }

                $option_data[] = array(
                'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
                'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
                'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                'name'                 => $option['name'],
                'type'                 => $option['type'],
                'value'                => $option['value'],
                'required'             => $option['required']
                );
            }
```

3- add this code inside the products array

```
'option'    => $option_data
```

4- Go to /catalog/view/theme/YOUR TEMPLATE/template/product/category.tpl and add this code to your product loop

```
        <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
         <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
          <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control">
            <option value="">SELECT EXTENDED LENGTH</option>
            <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

I'm still working in the javascript so I can add product to the cart with quantity and options without going into the product's page. Thanks