# How to display product option images in category page - Opencart 2.x

Tags: opencart2.x

I want to show product image options (available colors) in category/manufacturer/special/modules templates. Not active clickable options but just images.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question in SO [How to add product options in category page in opencart 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489886/how-to-add-product-options-in-category-page-in-opencart-2-0) if you know PHP you can make it work, but if your noobie - just buy extension and save your time.

Comment: The answer there is not confirmed and I already tried it - it's not working. Also the solution there is much more complicated with adding the product with chosen option to cart directly from category page and so on.

Comment: Well, if you tried it already, I suggest output product option images (using $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($product_id)) by product ID and then creating simple foreach in the view with needed data.